# Possibilities of a function range

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Let $f$ be a function from $\{A,B\} \to \{1,2,3,4\}$.

How many possibilities are there for the range of $f$?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: Range is a subset of the co domain

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Since there is more than one possible function, I changed *the* function to *a* function.

Comment: as @AdityaDwivedi noted, the range is a subset of $\{1,2,3,4\}$. So a good starting point might be to count the number of possible subsets of $\{1,2,3,4\}$. You should then ponder whether or not every subset is a valid range or if subsets exist, which can not possibly be a range. E.g. consider the empty set. Recount when you know which subsets are valid.

Comment: is the possibilities for the range of f to be : (2 to the power of 4)-1, 2^4 -1=15

Comment: Since $f$ is a function, $A$ can have only one image and $B$ can have only one image.  Therefore, the range may contain at most two elements of the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ and must contain at least one of those elements.

Comment: if f is one-to-one, then how can i find the different possibilities are there for
the range of f?

Comment: The problem does not say the function is one-to-one.  If it were, there would be four choices for the image of $A$ and three choices for the image of $B$, giving $4 \cdot 3 = 12$ one-to-one functions $f: \{A, B\} \to \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$.  Adding the number of constant functions will give you your result.